# how to read a file not from the beginning nor until the end

Tags: python, readline

I'm very new to python, and I'm stumbling upon a quite trivial issue.

I have a file called myfile.txt that looks like this:

```
some lines
that
I don't really need
and that 
can be skipped
START FROM THE NEXT ONE
  555555555555555
  555999999999999
  555333333333333
  555111111111111
  555333333333333
****
I don't need 
any 
of these
```

I want to print only the lines after 'START FROM THE NEXT ONE' up until the '****' (excluded).
The file contents may change over time, so I can't rely on the line number.

I came out with the following:

```
lines = open("myfile.txt","r").readlines() 

#solution n 1
for x, line in enumerate(lines):                                      
  if 'START FROM THE' in line:
    for j in range(x+1,len(lines)):
      if '****' in lines[j]:
        break  
      print(lines[j])
    break


#solution n 2
startWriting= False                                  
for line in lines:
    if startWriting:
        if '****' in line:
            break
        print(line)
    elif 'START FROM THE' in line:
        startWriting = True
```

They both work, but they are ugly. I'm wondering: is there a better solution to do this? Something not so wordy, with fewer conditions and nested loops? A cleaner and faster way?

I also tried this:

```
#solution n 3
wanted = [x for x in lines if x.startswith('  5')]     #THIS WORKS
for line in wanted:
    print(line)
```

But I'm reluctant to base my selection on the first char. What if they do not start with '5' anymore? I'm screwed!

Thanks for your patience and support. Any answer you want to throw at me will be highly regarded and very much appreciated.

Comment: I think your second solution is pretty good, I'm not sure how you would improve upon that without reducing flexibility or code simplicity.

Comment: you should try this https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

Comment: Welcome to the guild of software developers! "They both work, but they are ugly." is written on our coat of arms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want to print only the lines after 'START FROM THE NEXT ONE' up until the '****' (excluded)." **What is the rule that tells you** where to start? Should it skip a specific number of lines? A specific number of characters? Search the input until it finds that exact text? Search until it finds text that matches some kind of pattern? Something else?

Comment: Keep in mind that if the rule is based on analyzing the contents of the file to find a marker, then the code will have to *find the marker*, which entails reading starting at the beginning - since the marker could be anywhere, the code needs to look everywhere, in an organized way, until it is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the start and end identifiers are always present you can use the split method to print the lines needed.

1. split the text into a list of two strings, at the start identifier, then the second string in the list would contain the text needed and the the end identifier
2. we split this again, this time with end identifier and take the first element from the new list to get the text needed

**Code**

```
read_text = open("myfile.txt", "r").read()

print(read_text.split('START FROM THE NEXT ONE')[1].split('****')[0])
```

**Output**

```
  555555555555555
  555999999999999
  555333333333333
  555111111111111
  555333333333333
```

if the start or end identifiers could be absent you can use the try catch method to catch the exception:

```
read_text = open("myfile2.txt", "r").read()
try:
    print(read_text.split('START FROM THE NEXT ONE')[1].split('****')[0])
except IndexError:
    print('start or end identifiers absent')
```